# Using phonegap, any way to link to a view controller in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have tried to search this but haven't really found what I was looking for.
It appears the "child browser" plugin might have done what I wanted, but it appears to be depreciated.

I have a phonegap based project, but Id like to have an in-app settings page that interacts with the settings bundle that doesn't appear to be possible with phonegap itself.

Is there a way to create a viewcontroller in xcode that would be the settings page and be able to access it via phonegap?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use cordova.exec API to communicate between native functionality and hybrid app.

make sure you already define your plugin in your config.xml

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Implementing the plug-in by using Objective-C code

CustomPlugin.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface CustomPlugin : CDVPlugin

- (void)sayHello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

CustomPlugin.m

```
#import "CustomPlugin.h"

    @implementation CustomPlugin

    - (void)sayHello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{

        NSString *responseString =
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World, %@", [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]];

        CDVPluginResult *pluginResult =
            [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:responseString];

        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }

    @end
```

Calling a plug-in from JavaScript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH DATO!!!! I really appreciate your help with this!
I will try this out and mark it answered if all goes well!